# Brief Complex Analysis Problem

Tags: complex-analysis

With $ω = se^{iϕ}$, where $s ≥ 0$ and $ϕ ∈ R$, solve the equation $z^{n} = ω$ in $C$ where $n$ is a natural number. How many solutions are there?

What I have so far:

$ln(z^n)=n ln(z)$=$ln(w)$

$n=\frac{ln(w)}{ln(z)}= \frac{ln(se^{iϕ})}{ln(z)}$.

I am sure there is probably more than one solution, but I am not sure how to find it.

Comment: what branch of $\ln$ are you using? Be careful with it, even in the principal branch $\ln(z^n)\neq n\ln(z)$. For example $\ln(i^2)=-i\pi$ and $2\ln(i)=i\pi$. For your problem you must use the De Moivre formula and obtain the $n$ distinct solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THEOREM ($n$-roots of a complex number)** Let $\omega=se^{i\theta}$ $s>0$, then the equation $z^n=\omega$ has the next $n$ solutions
$$
z_k= s^{1/n} \exp\left( {i\left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}\right) }\right) \ \ \ k=0,1, \cdots, n-1.
$$
**PROOF:**
It suffices to show that for all $k \in \{ 0, 1 , \cdots, n-1\}$, $z_k^n=\omega$, indeed
$$
z_k^n = \left[ s^{1/n} \exp\left( {i\left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}\right) }\right) \right]^n = s \exp\left( i\left(\theta+2\pi k\right) \right)=s\exp(i\theta)=se^{i\theta}=\omega \ \ \blacksquare
$$